# How to sortby more than one value in pyspark

Tags: python-2.7, lambda, apache-spark, pyspark

I am playing around with Spark. I tried the sortBy function in spark with some sample data

```
tmp = [('e', 1), ('b', 2), ('1', 3), ('d', 4), ('2', 5),('a',1)]
sc.parallelize(tmp).sortBy(lambda (x,y): y).collect()
```

This works fine and sorts by the integer value in the key value pair. What is required to sort as per key after sorting it integer wise?

```
sc.parallelize(tmp).sortBy(lambda (x,y): y,x).collect()
```

says x is not defined.

Desired output

```
('a', 1),('e',1) ('b', 2), ('1', 3), ('d', 4), ('2', 5)
```

Comment: yes that did the trick. Please mention this as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried,

`sc.parallelize(tmp).sortBy(lambda (x, y): (y, x)).collect()`?

`sortBy(lambda (x, y): y, x)` is a function call with 2 arguments in Python.